# Typescript React event handler types

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Using the code below i have been unsuccessful in trying to convert my components to Typescript.

The issue i have lies within the `handleChange` function where the `event.target` types don't seem to have the correct properties?. If i change this to an inline arrow function i can see the type inference is `React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>` so the event type looks correct.

My react types are `"@types/react": "^16.8.23",`

```
import * as React from "react";

export default class SignIn extends React.Component<SignInProps, SignInState> {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: ''
        };
    }

    handleChange(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
        const type = event.target.type; // Property 'type' does not exist on type 'EventTarget & HTMLInputElement'.
        const value = event.target.value; // Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget & HTMLInputElement'.
        // do other stuff
    }

    async handleSubmit(event) {
        // do stuff
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <form id="sign-in" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Email address" type="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" />
                <input onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Password" type="password" />
                <input type="submit" />
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

I have noticed that if i click into the definitions i see

```
interface EventTarget { }
interface Document { }
interface DataTransfer { }
interface StyleMedia { }

interface Element { }

interface HTMLElement extends Element { }
... excluded for brevity
interface HTMLInputElement extends HTMLElement { }
```

Is it normal for these to be totally empty? Could this be the reason why it thinks there are no types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Empty type definitions are here for `ReactNative` when no dom library is included in a project. In a React project that targets a browser, these types come from a dom library.

You may have forgotten to add the dom libraries to your `tsconfig.json` file, make sure this is included in this file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
        // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That was correct, i copied and pasted my `tsconfig.json` from some sample code. Thanks